# ssh tunnel in and connect to local machine

Tags: networking, server, ssh, tunnel

Have a server setup and I can ssh in with putty via port forward and open a gui page, and webmin and command line.

Once I have logged in, I want to be able to access other ip addresses via web page on that network.

webmin http tunnel will allow access to outside webpages, but cannot access any addresses on the same network.

Is this even possible?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks for the reply & sorry not clear. By same network I mean on the same network as the server. So if my server is at 10.10.10.10, I want to be able to access 10.10.10.11 as well as other ip's. I connect to the network from my remote office via putty. From the remote office I can connect to the server webmin using localhost:10000. while in webmin, I hit http tunnel and I can connect to www.google.com however I cannot connect to 10.10.10.11 through http tunnel. DOes that help, or make it worse :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear from your question what you are trying to do and what problem you are having.

When you say "webmin http tunnel will allow access to outside webpages, but cannot access any addresses on the same network." it is ambiguous what 'same network' means and how you are trying to access (host name, ip address).

I can not determine if your problem is DNS or networking or ssh.

In general, tunnelling http over ssh is simple.

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 user@server
```

You then configure your browser (firefox) to use a proxy, localhost on port 8080

There is a great discussion on how to do this and optimize both the server and firefox here:

https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html